# Update AD password for username in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, active-directory, password

we are using SharePoint 2010.

Need reference articles for foll. requirement:
There is a webpart with 3 textbox's for username, original password and new password.

We need to allow user to be able to change his password. What is the best practice to implement this? Please note that we do not want to purchase/reuse solutions from codeplex /others, instead we need to create this from scratch for various reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is very good blog which change the Password in Active directory from sharepoint.

[Change the Active Directory User Password Through SharePoint](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/Pages/Change-the-Active-Directory-User-Password-Through-SharePoint.aspx)

Create a web part and give the user ability to change the password.

[Change Password Web Part for SharePoint 2010](http://www.ashokraja.me/post/Change-Password-Web-Part-for-SharePoint-2010.aspx)

Comment: thanks for answer. This http://www.ashokraja.me/post/Change-Password-Web-Part-for-SharePoint-2010.aspx looks more promissing.

Comment: Hi Waqas, the post provides solution to change password of logged in user. I need to change password of the username entered in textbox, What do you think I should do to solve? webpart or applicaiton page?

Comment: that is starting point, you have to amend it accodingly...instead of getting the current user you can run the queery on the based of the text box selection....i think it cause too much traffic from Sharepoint to AD and ad to Sharepoint....performance issue...I would prefer an Application page.

Comment: I guess the only option to solve this is by using LDAP as an impersonated user who has privilege to make changes to AD...